# Can I calculate the checksum of a file as I create it?

Tags: tar, checksum, tee

I am creating a large `tar` archive and I would like to create the checksum of the archive too. I could achieve it like this:

```
$ tar cfz archive.tar.gz files
$ sha256sum archive.tar.gz > archive.tar.gz.sha256sum
```

But the archive file is huge and on slow media, so I'd prefer not to have to read it all in again after writing it out.

Can I build a pipeline that will hash the file as it writes it? I thought maybe I could do this with the `tee` utility, but that only writes to a file, not to the standard input of another command.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question:

Yes, you can use tee and bash process substitution:

```
tar cfz - files | tee >(sha256sum) | cat > archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: Minor improvements:  You probably don't need the "`| cat`" part, you can just write it directly.  You also probably want the subcommand (the "`(sha256sum)`" to write somewhere, i.e. `(sha256sum >archive.tar.gz.sha256sum)`

Comment: Just use `| tee archive.tar.gz | sha256sum` then.